# Migration SVN to GIT with .svnignore file to .gitignore file

Tags: git, svn

I am trying to migrate an svn repository to a git repository. Below are the steps I am following:

Step 1: Collecting svn authors information using:

```
svn log -q http://localhost:8086/svn/project1/ | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > authors-transform.txt
```

Step 2: git-svn clone with standard repository structure:

```
git svn clone http://localhost:8086/svn/project1/ --no-metadata -A authors-transform.txt --stdlayout --prefix "" -s  ~/temp
```

Step 3: Entering into my home temp directory:

```
cd ~/temp;
```

Step 4: To verify local and remote branches I used the command below:

```
$ git branch -a

 * master
 remotes/branch-A
 remotes/tags/1.0
 remotes/trunk
```

Step 5: For proper git tag convention I am using the following script:

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/tags | cut -d / -f 4- | grep -v @ | while read tagname; do git tag "$tagname" "tags/$tagname"; git branch -r -d "tags/$tagname"; done
```

Step 6: To move the remote references like remotes/branch-A I used this script:

`git for-each-ref refs/remotes | cut -d / -f 3- | grep -v @ | while read branchname; do git branch "$branchname" "refs/remotes/$branchname"; git branch -r -d "$branchname"; done`

Step 7 : Verifying all the branches and tags:

```
$ git tag
  1.0

$ git branch
  master
  trunk
```

Step 8 : Cleaning my trunk branch:

```
$ git branch -d trunk
```

Step 9 : Creating github repository with a name of Samsung

Step 10 : Adding remote origin for communication of my local git repo with remote repo:

```
$git remote add origin https://github.com/tppalani/Samsung.git
```

Step 11 : Pushing all tags and branches to the github repository:

```
$ git push --all
$ git push --tag
```

Done! Ok, when I am logging my GitHub repository I have all the files having correct data without missing.

**Here is my question:** 
At the start, I have one file from the svn repository, .svnignore, in the gitHub repository. How can I rename this file to .gitignore?

Also, I would like to transfer all the .svnignore properties to .gitignore properties files. How can I perform this action before pushing all the branches and tags?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Team, Could you please some one help on this ?